# How to create a Joomla 3.0 component for Library-search

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I'm new to Joomla component development and I havent create a component before. My client suddenly asked to create a component for his site (Library-Search...) What it does is searching for books/publications in the library... How can I do this I have no idea how to create joomla components since i havent created before?? how many days it will take to create this component?

Comment: What format are you getting the information in? Also what kinds of fields?

Answer (score 0):

There are few links you can use, you need to have good understanding on MVC pattern

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/3.0/Introduction

http://www.joomlatutorials.com/joomla-tutorials/joomla-3-0-tutorials.html

http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_1.7_and_Joomla_Platform_11.1

http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1

http://developer.joomla.org/manual/

Comment: Quite a few if you haven't built a component before :)

Answer (score 0):

**First:**
You need to plan for the database.

**2nd:**
Use one of the component creator websites which convert your DB plan into component ready to install.

```
(ex: jc-creator.com ) - free
```

this will be a good start to learn the structure by reading the code and edit it.

**3th:**
You will need to create a plugin for the search as it's not come with Jc-creator.
copy and edit (easy to edit) one of the search plugins in joomla

```
(ex : plugins\search\content)
```

Zip the files and install it again to your joomla.

You can contact jc-creator team via twitter they helped me